# PHP Regex for deleting content inside quotes following by bracket

Tags: php, regex, cpu-word

I want to ask about how to deleting content inside quotes that followed by bracket?

For example, I have a string :

> $text = 'I have a dog. My dog is cute. "I have a cat". My cat is lazy.
>   "I have a bird" (I said). Come to my house! "You sure?" and I said
>   "Yes, of course" (2009)';

I want result like this:

> I have a dog. My dog is cure. "I have a cat". My cat is lazy. Come to
>   my house! "You sure?" and I said.

I already create this regex:

```
$return_value = preg_replace('/ "[^"]+"+ \([^\(]+\) /', ' ', $text);
```

But the result just cut at beginning sentences, not all sentences.

Anyone know to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With input:

> I have a dog. My dog is cute. "I have a cat". My cat is lazy. "I have a bird" (I said). Come to my house! "You sure?" and I said "Yes, of course" (2009).

And using:

```
/ "[^"]+" \([^()]+\)(?:\.(?!\s*$))?/
```

You get:

> I have a dog. My dog is cute. "I have a cat". My cat is lazy. Come to my house! "You sure?" and I said.

You had a whitespace after the `\)` in your regex which prevented a match. I used `(?:\.(?!\s*$))?` which means match a dot only if it's not at the end of the string.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gP7pA7)

Comment: Thank You, Your solution works too.. But anyone can explain what is the different Your method and xdazz method? And which is better?

Comment: @CrossVander The differences are that xdazz's also (1) matches at the beginning of strings, (2) empty quotes `""`, (3) multiple spaces between the closing quote and first paren, (4) removes the final period no matter what. For my part, I altered your regex as least as possible while still carry out the task you mentioned, by not making any assumptions. xdazz has a couple of assumptions which will make it work for some variances (desired or not) of the format you mentioned too.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo preg_replace('/"[^"]*"\s*\([^)]*\)\.?/', '', $text);
```